# Website not showing in Google search

Tags: search, google, seo

I have a site hosted at Brinkster and all keywords are there, but I still can't get it to show up in a Google search.

I thought if I searched for it by domain name, it would show up in the Google search results.

Can anyone explain why it's not showing up?

Comment: Not really programing related…

Comment: what if I say its HTML CSS programming. :-) Any way dear if this problem is there in initial stage how then I will put my java application there...

Answer (score 3):

takes time.
add your site to web directories with good page rank.
still... takes time.

Comment: its been over 8-10 months... And yes how to add site to web directories with good page rank.  BTW then how when I write the domain name on google search page my site is there ??

Comment: do you have original contents? title tags, h tags and keywords optimized? get inbound links from other sites. its not easy to climb the google ladder. even more because of panda farmers update

Answer (score 1):

You can read about [SEO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_engine_optimization) which is a set of techniques and guidelines on how to construct a page in way of improving its visibility on search engines like Google.

Take in mind that it might take some time until search engines crawl your website and add it to their index.

Answer (score 0):

Google inclusion is by no means automatic. Without knowing anything about your site, here is what Google looks at generally: (caveat, they change the specifics all the time)
1. Use web standards to markup your text. Use h1, p, a, etc. Avoid laying out non-tabular data in tables.
2. Google can't read images. Only use images for headlines if you are doing image replacement.
3. Google can't really read flash.
4. Google usually ignores JavaScript. If you use a lot of AJAX or encase links in it, you have crippled your site in the rankings.
5. Avoid any black hat technique ever used. No white text on a white background, link farms, stuffing keywords into metatags, redirects that intended to show google one page and your visitors another.
6. Pay attention to your page-ranking which, by the way, is affected by all of the above. One client used all images in tables (how 90's) and they didn't come up for the company name. Their page rank was low.
7. Lastly and most importantly, Google counts in-coming links from reliable sites. If no one links to you, you are invisible.

Comment: does hosting the site on free server like Brinkster may cause such problem ? Rest my site is almost completely HTML/CSS validated. But yes may be very short of inblund links...

Answer (score 0):

First, to make sure that it doesn't show up, do a site Google search like `site:www.example.com`. If it still doesn't show up, then try to submit your website at  https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/submit-url . Then, all you can do is wait. Wait for a week or so and every day check back to see if it is submitted. If it still isn't submitted, that means that Google thinks your website isn't work submitting. The best thing you can do then is to just continue updating your site like normal, and sign up for Google Webmaster Tools. This tool will most likely tell you the problem with your site, if Google can't crawl it, or if it gets a error.